# (of + how) how sholud I understand the grammar

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I have a question about (of + how)
In those sentence,

> It's just a realistic assessment of how the world works.

> that they're learning, is positive evidence of how that language works.

> I wouldn't tell the story of how I paid for college,

> "Talk to me about the mechanics of how you did what you did."

> the question of how could we study this stuff scientifically?

> Mayors are considering that idea of how you can actually

To me, I do not know why I need "of" before "how"
It makes sense to me even though without "of" before how
Can someone explain to me or tell me what kind of grammar I need to study?

Comment: You need preposition ***of*** because it carries the sense of ***concerning, about***. And you *also* need ***how*** because in every case, the "subject noun" that ***concerning, about*** refers to is ***how = the way in which** [something happens]*. It may not be the most idiomatic way of saying it, but I think in all your examples it's quite possible to replace ***of how*** with ***concerning the way in which***.

Comment: There is some disagreement among grammarians as to whether the _how_ expressions in examples like yours are relative clauses or subordinate interrogative ones. In the relative reading, the _how_ expressions are noun phrases functioning as object complement of the preposition "of".  In the interrogative reading, "how" is an adverb and they are subordinate interrogative clauses functioning as complement of "of" (cf. "It's just a realistic assessment of the answer to the question 'How does the world work?'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the preposition *of* because that is how words like *idea*, *story*, *assessment*, *evidence*, *question*, connect to their complements.

While FumbleFingers' argument **about** the meaning of the connection has some mnemomic usefulness, in the end the question **of** what preposition is required by a particular word is not reliably rule-governed or predictable. Those words that you used take *of*; *argument* takes *about*; *discussion* can take either.